# Tensor Product $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$

Tags: commutative-algebra, tensor-products

I believe that the tensor product $\mathbb{Q} / \mathbb{Z} \otimes \mathbb{Z} / 2\mathbb{Z}$ is trivial, i.e. any element is 0, but apparently there are in fact 2 elements. Why is this?

Comment: What's your argument that it's trivial? ...

Comment: More generally, if $D$ is divisible and $T$ is torsion then $D\otimes T=0$.

Comment: (a/b) $\otimes$ 1 = (a/2b + a/2b) $\otimes$ 1 = (a/2b) $\otimes$ 1 + (a/2b) $\otimes$ 1 = (a/2b) $\otimes$ (1+1) =  (a/2b) $\otimes$ 0 = 0

Comment: Where does your "apparently" come from?

Comment: The ‘apparently’ came from an exam solution mark scheme which I’m now doubting is correct

Comment: If the solution said $\Bbb Q/Z\otimes\Bbb Z/2\Bbb Z$ has two elements, that's wrong. In that case, I suspect someone's error was thinking about the $2$-primary component of $\Bbb Q/\Bbb Z$ as an inverse limit instead of a direct limit.